# Scroll loop on mobile (not Infinite scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to create a seamless looping webpage where the content repeats over and over without having to actually duplicate the divs. I came across a [THIS CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWQKqW), which is exactly what I was looking for, but the mobile experience is really glitchy and flickers when repositioning to the top of the page.

Any solves for mobile? Or edits to this JS?

See below and thanks!

```js
var doc = window.document,
  context = doc.querySelector('.js-loop'),
  clones = context.querySelectorAll('.is-clone'),
  disableScroll = false,
  scrollHeight = 0,
  scrollPos = 0,
  clonesHeight = 0,
  i = 0;

function getScrollPos () {
  return (context.pageYOffset || context.scrollTop) - (context.clientTop || 0);
}

function setScrollPos (pos) {
  context.scrollTop = pos;
}

function getClonesHeight () {
  clonesHeight = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < clones.length; i += 1) {
    clonesHeight = clonesHeight + clones[i].offsetHeight;
  }

  return clonesHeight;
}

function reCalc () {
  scrollPos = getScrollPos();
  scrollHeight = context.scrollHeight;
  clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

  if (scrollPos <= 0) {
    setScrollPos(1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
  }
}

function scrollUpdate () {
  if (!disableScroll) {
    scrollPos = getScrollPos();

    if (clonesHeight + scrollPos >= scrollHeight) {
      // Scroll to the top when you’ve reached the bottom
      setScrollPos(1); // Scroll down 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
      disableScroll = true;
    } else if (scrollPos <= 0) {
      // Scroll to the bottom when you reach the top
      setScrollPos(scrollHeight - clonesHeight);
      disableScroll = true;
    }
  }

  if (disableScroll) {
    // Disable scroll-jumping for a short time to avoid flickering
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      disableScroll = false;
    }, 40);
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);

context.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate);
}, false);

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);
}, false);








// Just for this demo: Center the middle block on page load
window.onload = function () {
  setScrollPos(Math.round(clones[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + getScrollPos() - (context.offsetHeight - clones[0].offsetHeight) / 1));
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Loop {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
}

::scrollbar {
  display: none;
}







body {
  font-family: "Avenir Next", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.red {
  background: #FF4136;
}
.green {
  background: #2ECC40;
}
.blue {
  background: #0074D9;
}
.orange {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<main class="Loop js-loop">
  <section class="green">
    <h1>FIRST</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="red">
    <h1>For</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="blue">
    <h1>All</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="orange">
    <h1>And</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="blue">
    <h1>All</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="red">
    <h1>LAST</h1>
  </section>

  <!--
  These blocks are the same as the first blocks to get that looping illusion going.
  You need to add clones to fill out a full viewport height.
  -->
  <section class="green is-clone">
    <h1>FIRST</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="red is-clone">
    <h1>For</h1>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: where is you JS placed in Html? you should run it on chrome audits to check where the performance is being affected.

Comment: In the head. Tried moving with no impact on the flickering on iOS.